# Is it possible to have bidirectional relationships in Microsoft Access?

Tags: vba, database, microsoft-access, visual-basic

I have a database including two tables for suppliers and people:

[image]

the suppliers table has a look up column where one can select the people relevant to that supplier from the people table. and there is a company look up column on the people table that point to the company they work for from the suppliers table. Now I have to update these two tables separately which is cumbersome and error prom. I want to automate this process so when either of the tables is updated the other one is synced automatically.

I would appreciate it if you could help me know whether this is possible and how to do it.    I am ok with Visual Basic  / VBA macros if that is the only way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the accessdatabaseengine.exe or accessdatabaseengine_X64.exe
to be allowed to use this method.

```
Dim cn, rs  'For database access

    Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    
    connectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0; Data Source=d:\inventory.accdb"
    cn.Open connectionString
    rs.ActiveConnection = connectionString
```

Then later in the code

```
cn.Execute "<your SQL statement goes here update table1>"
cn.Execute "<your SQL statement goes here update table2>"
```

SQL example here

```
cn.Execute "update table set name='"&name&"' where othervalue=`"&othervalue&"';"
```